# Почему для работы #pragma omp cancel нужно устанавливать переменную окружения?

Tags: c++, openmp

С чем связано то, что для включения возможности остановки потоков в OpenMP нужно устанавливать переменную окружения (OMP_CANCELATION)?

Почему для этого нет какой-то внутренней переменной для управления внутри программы?

Comment: А какой ответ вы ожидаете получить? Ну да, спецификация опенмп старая, убогая, и вся завязана на переменные окружения, но радикально что-то менять наверное уже позно.

Comment: @user7860670, ну вот есть функция set_num_threads(), которая переписывает параметр, который тоже может устанавливаться переменной окружения. Т.е. возможность сделать внутренний параметр есть, но почему то не сделали. Были ли на это какие то причины? или просто потому-что спецификация "старая", "убогая"?